# Using a variable in php function returning value

Tags: php, postgresql, function, variables

I have a function that is supposed to give me a staff members name from his ID number so my php is like this

```
$staffId = $_GET['staff_id'];
$staff = staff_load($staffId);
```

and my function is like this

```
function staff_load()
{
$dbh = dbh_get(); //connects to database

$sql = 'select user_name from user_staff where user_id = ?';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$staff = $stmt->fetch();

dbh_free($dbh); //disconnects from database
return $staff;
}
```

But when I try and use the $staff variable, it shows nothing. I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried a bunch of variants and gotten nowhere except frustrated.

```
<td>Book for ' . $staff . '</td>
```

Comment: First, `var_dump` your var `$staff` and tell what it returns.

Comment: Your function definition (`function staff_load()`) needs to accept the value passed to it (`function staff_load($id)`), and bind it in the SQL query

Comment: `function staff_load()` takes no parameter, it should be `function staff_load($id)` and then inside your `execute()` add `execute([$id])`

Comment: You should be getting errors from this code. Look at your error log

Comment: it says bool(false)

Comment: You `->prepare()` a query, **but you dont bind the parameter to it**

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I'm lost, I tried var_dump and got bool(false)

Comment: function staff_load() , You forgot to mention staffid in the function as parameter i guess

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_` or `PDO`?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you forgot to include the parameter in your function definition:

```
function staff_load($id) {
```

Then you need to bind the parameter of the prepared statement.

```
$sql = 'select user_name from user_staff where user_id = $1';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
```

Next, `fetch()` returns an array, you need to extract the `user_name` element from the array:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    $staff = $row['user_name'];
} else {
    $staff = false;
}
```

Comment: changed function to this but still nothing function staff_load($staffId)
{
    $dbh = dbh_get();

    $sql = 'select user_name from user_staff where user_id = :staffId';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bindParam(':staffId', $staffId);
    
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
    $staff = $row['user_name'];
} else {
    $staff = false;
}
dbh_free($dbh);
 return $staff;
}

Comment: Are there any errors? Have you enable PDO's error signalling? Can you confirm that you're using PDO as I assumed?

Comment: I assumed it was PDO because `$stmt->fetch()` is the syntax for that API. What API are you using?

Comment: can it be written without api? I'm not a programmer, but doesn't have pdo in other functions. It's just php to postgresql database

Comment: this is a statement that works function user_options()
{
 $dbh = dbh_get();
 $options = '';

 $sql = 'select user_id, user_name from user_staff where user_id>7 ORDER BY user_name';
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 while (true) {
  $r = $stmt->fetch();
  if (is_bool($r)) break;
  $options .= '<option value="' . $r['user_id'] . '">' . $r['user_name'] . '</option>';
 }

 dbh_free($dbh);
 return $options;
}

Comment: @Kilisi There's always an API. Whatever function you use to make database queries is the API.

Comment: well, I tried what you had, and it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what functions you're using. According to http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php, the functions for making PostgreSQL queries all begin with `pg_`, but you're not calling those functions in the code you posted. I guess it's being done in the database class you're using.

Comment: I've changed my answer to use a prepared statement as described in http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to pass parameter to staff_load function

```
function staff_load($staffId)
```

secondly you should bind parameter

```
$sql = 'select user_name from user_staff where user_id = :user_id';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $staffId);
```

Comment: user_id should equal the $staffId value